# How to setup Cloudfare ssl certificate to AWS EC2 NGINX server?

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, nginx, amazon-ec2, ssl-certificate

Well, I have already created a certificate from Cloudfare,
eg, 1.  **cloudfare-private.pem** ,
2.  **cloudfare-public.pem**
now I want to upload in amazon ec2 which is on Nginx server, I am unable to get the proper documentation regarding how to upload make my sites secure. kindly help me

Comment: in your nginx configuration file add ssl certificate. 
here is the tutorial link : https://www.ssls.com/knowledgebase/how-to-install-an-ssl-certificate-on-a-nginx-server/

Comment: let me try that